# I want to make my program execute till I manually exit it

Tags: vb.net, loops, iteration

I have created a console program using vb
. Net to calculate an entered number factorial, but it only executes once before I exiting, how can I make the program run until the user wants to exit? 
Here is the code I used

```vb
Module factorial 

 

    Dim factorial = 1, i, num As Integer

    Sub Main()

        Console.Write("Enter a number to find a factorial of it : ")

        num = Console.ReadLine()

 

        factorial = 1

        For i = 1 To num

            factorial = factorial * i

        Next

 

        Console.WriteLine("Factorial of {0} is {1}", num, factorial)

 

       

 

    End Sub

 

End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

`Console.ReadKey()` will allow you to make program waiting for pressing any key.

> [Console.ReadKey Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

If you need your program calculating more and more factorials, you should wrap all the code into infinite loop like that:

```
Do
    Something
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

To process more than one input from the user, you need to put your code inside a loop. You will need a way for the user to indicate that it's time to finish (for example by typing "Quit" instead of a number.

You should also make sure the string entered by the user is valid before converting it to an Integer. You can do that by using [Integer.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Finally, you should allow for the possiibility that the factorial is very large. Using a Long instead of an Integer for the factorial will help, but the factorial may still be too large, so you can use Try/Catch to check for an Overflow and send an error message. If you want to handle numbers of any size, you can research [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
Module factorial
    Sub Main()
        Do
            Console.Write("Enter a number to find its factorial, or Quit to end the program:")
            Dim inString As String = Console.ReadLine
            If inString.ToUpper = "QUIT" Then Exit Sub

            Dim num As Integer
            If Integer.TryParse(inString, num) Then
                Dim factorial As Long = 1
                Try
                    For i As Integer = 2 To num
                        factorial *= i
                    Next
                    Console.WriteLine("Factorial of {0} is {1}", num, factorial)
                Catch ex As OverflowException
                    Console.WriteLine("Factorial of {0} is too large", num)
                End Try
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub
End Module
```